# Docker health check always returning as unhealthy

Tags: python, docker, health-check

Docker Healthcheck is failing, so its showing as unhealthy.

Here is the `Dcokerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "flask"]
HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=10s --start-period=55s \
   CMD curl -f --retry 10 --max-time 15 --retry-delay 10 --retry-max-time 60 "http://localhost:8080/health" || exit 1   

CMD [ "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port",  "8080"]
```

Tried with below example, getting below error

```
$docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health }}' flask-app

Template parsing error: template: :1:13: executing "" at <.State.Health>: map has no entry for key "State"
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restx  import fields, Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
    
@api.route('/health', methods=['GET'])
class Health(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return { 'success': True, 'message': "healthy" }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

[image: Health API is working fine]

[image: Notice 'Unhealthy' status in the docker ps]

Comment: I wouldn't say it is unhealthy as the screenshot shows `"message": "healthy"`. It probably has something to do with your `docker inspect` query. I would run `docker inspect` and see if there's a `State`.

Comment: @MarkoE - Thank you for response. Task is to show the status healthy in the manifest. question updated with screenshot. notice the status there it is coming as `unhealthy`

Comment: @Laxmikant are you calling the correct health check API. I see it is calling http://localhost:8080/ instead of http://localhost:8080/health

Comment: @AkashRudra - I tried both, still same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you have curl installed in your container? It does not come with *python:3.8.5-alpine3.12*

Add these lines to your Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add curl
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. wondering how did I forget to check this silly mistake :). BTW Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

in `$docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health }}' flask-app`

remove the extra space after the word `json` on (`{{json .State.Health }}`)